# Android: Missing L1/L2/L3 cache size files

Tags: android, linux, arm64, cpu-cache

I want to find out the L1/L2/L3 caches' sizes of my Android phone from the command-line.
I used ADB to log into my Android phone and I've been trying to learn what the cache sizes are the usual way, from the files in /sys, but I found something odd.

I can read these files just fine, they say Data, and 1 for L1 data cache:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/type
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/level
```

However the size file does not exist, even though on other Linux-based systems it would:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/size
```

Is there another place to read the caches' size?
My kernel is 4.19.